# When is a limit of measure preserving maps also measure preserving?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, ergodic-theory

Take some compact space, for simplicity take the interval $[0,1]$.

Let $f_n:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be measure preserving, i.e. $\mu (f_n^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ for all lebesgue measurable $A \subset [0,1]$.

The question is under what kinds of convergence $f_n \to f$ do we also ensure that $f$ is measure preserving?

I think I can show that for $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ this holds. I'm now wondering about weak convergence $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2$? Anyone know the answer (and maybe a proof/counterexample)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = \{nx\}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.  Then $f_n \rightharpoonup \tfrac12$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Uh, is it immediate to see the convergence to 1/2 in L^2? Since the subsequence f_n(x) = { 2^n x} seems to be measure preserving, and seems to disagree with the convergence? It would be very helpful if you can hint at showing the L_2 convergence

Comment: @E-A It is similar to the proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: Thanks; drawing out f_n and seeing the zigzag and connecting it to the Fourier series conceptually as per your linked helped a lot.